# DropDownListFor: First option act as a placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my DropDownList field -

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Types"], "--Choose One--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

How do I make sure that the optionLabel: `--Choose One--` is displayed when nothing is selected and disappears when the list is showing, essentially acting as a placeholder?

**Edit 1**

I basically do not want the label to participate in jQuery validation so need to remove it on showing. Here is the jQuery snippet -

```
rules: {
    TypeId: {
        required: true
    }
}
```

But still `--Choose One--` is considered as a valid value and is marked as success -

[image: Choose One]

This is the html generated for the dropdownlist -

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TypeId must be a number." data-val-required="The TypeId field is required." id="TypeId" name="TypeId">
    <option value="">--Choose One--</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You would need to remove it using javascript/jquery of have a conditional `if` statement in you view to render the dropdown with or without the label option

Comment: do you want it to completly disappear from the dropdown list options? once option is selected?

Comment: @Zeeshan Yes, do not want to show in dropdownlist on showing and afterwards too as firstly, it is a required field and secondly, it interferes with jQuery validation.

Comment: @Sam, What do you mean it interferes with jQuery validation? (it doesn't)

Comment: @StephenMuecke If I want the field to be required: true, the first option is also considered as a value, which is not true.

Comment: Not it is not. The first option is rendered as `<option value>--Choose One--</option>` It does not have a value. If you want client side validation to ensure a value is required then your property `TypeID` needs to be `int?` (nullable) with the `[Required]` attribute

Comment: Assuming `TypeId` is marked as a required field in the model, no, the "empty" value would not be valid, as @StephenMuecke points out, so the validation plugin(s) should catch that. If that's not working, you need to include a more complete example of your code demonstrating that behavior.

Comment: @Sam, Note also (assuming `Types` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`), your code should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Types"] ...` to ensure its cast correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, it is like you said, somehow didn't get displayed in the post.

Comment: Your obviously using some jquery plugin which will be generating its own html. You need to post the html that's generated (and is there some reason your not using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TypeId)`)?

Comment: Something weird with `<option value="">..` By default, it will generate `<option value>..` (no `=""`) - are you sure that the correct html?. In any case, why are you adding `rules` for `TypeID`? If your using `jquery-validate.js` and jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js` its already added so its unnecessary (and may be a problem)

Comment: Yes, it is the correct html. How do I say a field is required if I do not add rules for it? And yes, I am using jquery-validate.js.

Comment: Which version of MVC? Are you using `jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js` for client side validation?

Comment: MVC 5.2.2 and yes, I am using jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js

Comment: I have tested MVC 3, 4 and 5 and it renders `<option value>` not `<option value="">` so something is interfering - perhaps some other javascript. Remove the rules and use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TypeId)` - they are already added for you (that's what the `data-val-*` attributes in the `<select>` are) and see if it works, but I can't guess what would be causing the problem with the label option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7u9j7er/1/)

```
$('#typeId').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).children('option[value=""]').length){
        $(this).children('option[value=""]').remove()
    }
});
```

it will remove options label from select whaen you choose something

Comment: I don't want to remove on change, but on showing (opening the dropdown, so the user is not able to select).

Comment: I changed the event to "focus" and it is fine. I was looking to find a more implicit solution though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var id=document.getElementById("TypeId").value; 
    if(id=="")
    { 
    //your code
        return false
    } 
</script>
```

you can use this validation if user select noting then your page not going to submit

Comment: 0 down vote
 
var id=document.getElementById("TypeId").value; if(id=="") { //your code return false }

you can use this validation if user select noting then your page not going to submit